# Haskell -- Main.hs:18:5: parse error on input ‘putStrLn’

Tags: haskell, syntax

```
module Main where

reportResults :: [String] -> [Int] -> IO ()
reportResults fileNames exitCodes = do
    putStrLn "All Files"
    putStrLn "---------"
    putStr.unlines $ map ("    " ++) fileNames
    putStrLn ""

    let problems = filter (\p -> fst p /= 0) $ zip exitCodes fileNames

    putStrLn "Problematic Files"
    putStrLn "-----------------"
    mapM_ (putStrLn . showProblem) problems
                where showProblem :: (Int, String) -> String
                      showProblem (c, f) = "    " ++ show c ++ " - " ++ f

    putStrLn "Done!"  -- "Parse error on input...". OK if this line is removed.

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let fileNames = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    let exitCodes = [0,   1,   2,   3]
    reportResults fileNames exitCodes
```

The code works fine if I comment out, or remove, the offending line (line 18), but I would really like to retain it and also understand what I'm doing wrong.  After trying many permutations and searching heaps, I still can't crack it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `where` clause. Define it as a `let` or outside the `reportResults`.

Comment: Unlike `let`, `where` is a part of the whole defining equation, and not of an expression. E.g. `(let x=1 in x) + 2` will evaluate to 3, while `(x where x=1) + 2` is a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you @Willem Van Onsem and @chi.  I now realise that the `do` syntax translates into all lines at the first indentation level being a bunch of (mainly monadic) function applications that declare what the reportResults variable is. With the offending `putStrLn "Done!"` commented out, the `where` clause came at the end, where it must come, if at all - and indented to the second level, providing as is its purpose, the bindings for any remaining variables above it.  Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `showProblem` function in a `let` clause, so:

```
reportResults :: [String] -> [Int] -> IO ()
reportResults fileNames exitCodes = do
    putStrLn "All Files"
    putStrLn "---------"
    putStr.unlines $ map ("    " ++) fileNames
    putStrLn ""

    let problems = filter (\p -> fst p /= 0) $ zip exitCodes fileNames

    putStrLn "Problematic Files"
    putStrLn "-----------------"
    let showProblem (c, f) = "    " ++ show c ++ " - " ++ f
    mapM_ (putStrLn . showProblem) problems
    putStrLn "Done!"  -- "Parse error on input...". OK if this line is removed.
```